# Google Drive - fetching deletions from folder

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

My goal is to find files trashed from a specific folder. If that is not possible, just finding recently trashed files will suffice.

My first attempt:

```cs
var listReq = driveApi.Files.List();
listReq.OrderBy = "modifiedTime desc";
listReq.Q = "'0Bxj123' in parents and trashed = true"; // 0Bxj123 is my folder ID
listReq.Execute(); 
var results = listReq.Files;
Console.WriteLine("{0} results", results.Count);
```

But this returns 0 results. I suspect the reason is, trashed files don't have a parent.

My second attempt, I thought, let's see if I can just find the trashed items and work with it from there:

```cs
var listReq = driveApi.Files.List();
listReq.OrderBy = "modifiedTime desc";
listReq.Q = "trashed = true";
listReq.Execute(); // Error: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file
```

In this case, just searching through deleted items results in an error, "insufficient permissions for this file."

OK, maybe I'm trying to browse deleted shared items? So I tried limiting my request to just my drive, attempt #3:

```cs
var listReq = driveApi.Files.List();
listReq.Spaces = "drive";
listReq.Corpora = "user";
listReq.OrderBy = "modifiedTime desc";
listReq.Q = $"trashed = true"; 
listReq.Execute(); // Error: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file
```

What am I missing here? How can I find items trashed from a specific folder? Or, failing that, how can I fetch deleted items without running into "not permitted" errors?

Comment: I tried reproducing this but to no avail as I wasn't receiving any errors when making the last two requests and the files were listed successfully. What scope/s are you using for this?

Comment: Thanks for trying, @ale13. Scope - I've created an API key used on my server in Google Developer Console. I've granted it access to the Google Drive API, unrestricted. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Can you check which exact scopes from this list [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) did you approve?